# Create and append HASH-ID key with value pairs to a file of JSON objects for each row using miller shell command

Tags: json, linux, shell, cmd, miller

I'm looking to create a `unique-ID/hash-ID` for each row in my `JSONs` file based on all the values in each `JSON object`

I started from this but not sure if I will have to be explicit columns name or if there's a way to include all columns without being explicit about column names.

```
mlr --json put -S '$hash_id=$f_name."".$l_name."".$title' then reorder -e -f job file.json
```

`file.json` Input:

```
{"f_nams":"Hana","title":"Mrs","l_name":"Smith"}
{"f_nams":"Mike","title":"Mr","l_name":"Larry"}
{"f_nams":"Jhon","title":"Mr","l_name":"Doe"}
```

Desired output:

```
{"f_nams":"Hana","title":"Mrs","l_name":"Smith","hash_id":"hash_value_based_on_all_columns"}
{"f_nams":"Mike","title":"Mr","l_name":"Larry","hash_id":"hash_value_based_on_all_columns"}
{"f_nams":"Jhon","title":"Mr","l_name":"Doe","hash_id":"hash_value_based_on_all_columns"}
```

Comment: `mlr` is an awesome tool to handle petty JSON manipulations and I don't think a hash create function exists in the latest version. Would you like to use an answer using `jq` a more powerful JSON parser? And also explain what is the nature of hash you are trying to create? `md5` or `sha` or `base64`? ( the latter is supported out-of-the-box in `jq`)

Comment: for sure I would like to explore `jq`. I will use `base64` for now. `sha` is also good for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input file.json is formatted as shown:

```
cat file.json
{"f_nams":"Hana","title":"Mrs","l_name":"Smith"}
{"f_nams":"Mike","title":"Mr","l_name":"Larry"}
{"f_nams":"Jhon","title":"Mr","l_name":"Doe"}
```

Then one way is to use the following perl script to produce the desired output:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne '
/"f_nams":"(\w+)","title":"(\w+)","l_name":"(\w+)"/ && do {
($fn,$tt,$ln)=($1,$2,$3);
$x=$fn . $tt . $ln;
chomp($hashvalue = encode_base64($x));
s/\}/,"hash_id":"$hashvalue"\}/;print}' file.json
```

Produces:

```
{"f_nams":"Hana","title":"Mrs","l_name":"Smith","hash_id":"SGFuYU1yc1NtaXRo"}
{"f_nams":"Mike","title":"Mr","l_name":"Larry","hash_id":"TWlrZU1yTGFycnk="}
{"f_nams":"Jhon","title":"Mr","l_name":"Doe","hash_id":"Smhvbk1yRG9l"}
```